# Pandas read_excel() date_parser gets the year wrong despite the fact that a correct format ("%b-%y") is given

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

My Excel file has dates looking like "Mar-21" to mean March of the year 2021. However, when I use pandas.read_excel() as shown in the following code snippet, the output displays dates with the current year, but sets the years that were in Excel as days of the month.

Shape of Source data:

[image: The way the data looks like in Excel]

Code snippet for reading the file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    io=input_excel_file,
    parse_dates=date_columns,
    date_parser=lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x, format="%b-%y"))
```

Preview of the resulting DataFrame:

[image: Resulting DataFrame has wrong years]

How do I get read_excel or Pandas to recognize that the digits in May-22 are for the year 2022, for example? Thanks in advance!

Update: Running `pandas.read_excel()` without the `parse_dates` and `date_parser` parameters, the code snippet looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(
    io=input_excel_file,)
```

and results in the following output:

[image: Running read_excel without explicitly parsing the dates]

Comment: Are you certain the underlying data is a string with that format, or is that just how Excel is displaying it?

Comment: if what @BeRT2me suggested is true (data in Excel is actually handled as Excel serial date), then pandas can't do much about it. It's actually the engine that loads the Excel file to a Python data structure that determines the outcome in your datetime column. You'll have to correct it in Excel. Or prepare for some tedious work-arounds.

Comment: Both of your, i.e. @BeRT2me's and FObersteiner's, observations totally make sense. It is possible that the source of the Excel document is in a locale where those dates could be written the way they are in the Excel file to mean what I explained, e.g. Mon-YY.

In this context, let's assume I do not have a way to edit the Excel spreadsheet and have to do any needed transformation in Python. What are my options?

Comment: Don't parse the dates during the `read_excel`, look at what the text output is in a dataframe instead. Then you can evaluate what format pandas is actually receiving.

Comment: @BeRT2me I have updated the question to include a preview of the output when running the code without the explicit date parsers.

Comment: That output is perfectly fine. It shows that the date values were properly treated as dates, and any empty cells were replaced with Nat (Not-a-Time)

Comment: Excel has actual numeric and date types. What you see in Excel is the value formatted using the cell's style and user's locale. That's a great demonstration why you should *never use two-digit years*. What you thought was the year was  actually the day of month. The actual *stored* value was `2022-05-22`.

Comment: Does the original Excel file contain bad data perhaps? Did someone enter `May 22` expecting this to be `May 2022`? You can check the unformatted value by clicking on the cell and checking the actual value in the edit line

Comment: Thanks everyone! As some of you already suggested, it seems like editing the Excel file is the most straightforward way of solving the problem. In the case where one doesn't have edit rights to the Excel file, this remains a problem I am curious about.

Anyone who knows stackoverflow procedures better, what should I do with the question? Provide the work-around as answer and accept it?